# Http Url Connection error

Tags: java, android, http

I am getting the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Target host must not be null, or set in parameters. scheme=null, host=null, path=CONNECT_URL
```

Following are my Global variables:

```
String CONNECT_URL = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Mumbai";
    int LAST_INDEX; 
    String NAME; 
    String TYPE; 
    String GREETING_YEAR; 
    String GREETING_GENERAL; 
    String RADIO_TYPE;
    InputStream ins = null;
    String result = null;
```

following is my parse function:

```
public void parse(){
        DefaultHttpClient http = new DefaultHttpClient(new BasicHttpParams()); 
        System.out.println("URL is: "+CONNECT_URL); 
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("CONNECT_URL");
        httppost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
        try{
            HttpResponse resp = http.execute(httppost); 
            HttpEntity entity = resp.getEntity();
            ins = entity.getContent(); 
            BufferedReader bufread = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ins, "UTF-8"), 8); 
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); 
            String line = null; 

            while((line = bufread.readLine()) != null){

                sb.append(line +"\n"); 

            }
            result = sb.toString(); 
            System.out.println("Result: "+result); 

        }catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("Error: "+e);
        }finally{
            try{
                if(ins != null){
                    ins.close();
                }
            }catch(Exception squish){
                System.out.println("Squish: "+squish); 
            }
        }



    }
```

I tried to refator it with other similar questions on SO, but my URL seems to be okay and it returns the JSON once I check the same URL from a browser, any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You´ve got

```
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("CONNECT_URL");
```

and looking to your code should be like

```
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(CONNECT_URL);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are passing "CONNECT_URL" in HttpPost object which is wrong. Use

```
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(CONNECT_URL) //instead of HttpPost("CONNECT_URL")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("CONNECT_URL");
```

should be

```
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(CONNECT_URL);
```

As a side note, Java convention dictates that variables are camel case (`connectUrl`) and constants are uppercase (`CONNECT_URL`).

Comment: Thank you for the friendly tip, I will definitely change it :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem comes from this line:

```
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("CONNECT_URL");
```

You are passing the string `"CONNECT_URL"` instead of passing the variable `CONNECT_URL` :)